# Show message if statement is false - foreach

Tags: custom-field, php

I got this PHP script from http://tutorialzine.com/2010/02/php-mysql-download-counter/ and integrate it to my wordpress successfully. It works but the "No Download File" message appears even the value is true. Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $value = get_post_custom_values("kpm_UploadFile");
    $url = ($value[0]);
    $tokens = explode('/', $url);
    $dlvalue = $tokens[sizeof($tokens)-1];

    if (current_user_can('read')) {

        foreach($files_array as $key => $val) {
        if ($dlvalue == $val){
            echo '<a href="http://drrknowledge.net/download.php?file='.urlencode($val).'"><strong>Download File</strong><br />'.$val.' has been downloaded <strong>'.(int)$file_downloads[$val].'</strong> times</a>';
            }else {
                echo 'No Download File';
            }
        }
    } else { echo 'Register to download';}
?>
```

What im trying to achieve here is to show the download file. If there is no file in "kpm_UploadFile" custom field or if its not present, a else statement saying "No Download File".

I can remove the

> echo 'No Download File';

but I want to show a message if there is no value.

Comment: And what is `files_array`? You do this in foreach loop, so for one $key this if is true and for other it can be false - I guess this is the reason you see this `No download File`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it's a lot of guessing, because I can't see the rest of your code, but something like this should work, I hope...

```
<?php
    $value = get_post_custom_values("kpm_UploadFile");
    $url = ($value[0]);
    $tokens = explode('/', $url);
    $dlvalue = $tokens[sizeof($tokens)-1];

    if (current_user_can('read')) {
        $found = 0;
        foreach ($files_array as $key => $val) {
            if ($dlvalue == $val) {
                $found = 1;
                echo '<a href="http://drrknowledge.net/download.php?file='.urlencode($val).'"><strong>Download File</strong><br />'.$val.' has been downloaded <strong>'.(int)$file_downloads[$val].'</strong> times</a>';
            }
        }
        if ( !$found ) {
            echo 'No Download File';
        }
    } else { echo 'Register to download';}
?>
```

Comment: Wow @Krzysiek Dróżdż you solved my problem mate. Thanks a lot. Working now!